# Render unicode text with wkhtmltoimage

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, character-encoding, wkhtmltoimage

Trying to use wkhtmltox to turn an HTML file to an image:

`./server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const wkhtmltox = require('wkhtmltox');

const app = express();
const converter = new wkhtmltox();

app.get('/tagslegend.png', (request, response) => {
  response.status(200).type('png');
  converter.image(fs.createReadStream('tagslegend.html'), { format: "png" }).pipe(response);
});

var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log('App listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

And `./tagslegend.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <dl>
      <dt>中文</dt><dd>In mandarin language.</dd>
    </dl>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting back an image of the above HTML, e.g. (how my browser would render it):

[image]

Instead I get back this:

[image]

How can I render that HTML to a png dynamically *with* the correct chinese characters and serve it to clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

to the `<head>` of the HTML document